# Появление элементов при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть множество сайтов с прописанным появлением элементов при скролинге. Это уже такой стандарт де-факто для лэндингов. Но как организовать появление элементов без скролинга, но при загрузке страницы?

Есть у нас три блока, к примеру:

```
<div id="block1">1</div>
<div id="block1">2</div>
<div id="block1">3</div>
```

И нужно, чтобы при полной загрузки страницы они появились, вылетели слева или просто были прозрачными и обрели opacity: 1.

Как это реализовать?

https://jsfiddle.net/ypj3qwqe/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block').each(function(index, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('#load:visible').length > 0) {
        $('#load:visible').hide();
      }
      $(el).css('display', 'inline-block');
    }, 2000 + 500 * index);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load">Загрузка...</div>
<div id="block1" class="block">1</div>
<div id="block1" class="block">2</div>
<div id="block1" class="block">3</div>
```

Comment: великолепно! Один вопрос - как присвоить несколько CSS-свойств? Или класс?